# Ap calculus question (gr.12)

Tags: integration

let $f(k)$ be a function determined as the average value of $h(x) = sin(x-k)$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$. Show that $f$ is a continuous function of $k$ and determine the maximum and minimum values of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $$f(k)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} {\sin(x-k) dx}$$ Therefore $$f(k)=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\cos(k)-\cos(\pi-k)\right)=\frac{2\cos k}{\pi}$$ Hint from here: 1) Differentiability implies continuiuty and 2) Set derivative to 0 for min and max (or just use common sense about what the cosine function does).

Comment: +1 for the common sense. It would be really weird to use calculus to get the minimum and maximum ._.

Comment: @chubakueno yeah I should have added "use common sense for continuity too and disregard everything else I said."

Comment: Wow thanks I didn't even consider that!!

Comment: lol just took in the "average value" part of the question..

Comment: nice do you get it now? :) average value means you take the integral over the region and then divide by the length of the region.

Comment: Yeah!! When I read it again I thought about the whole area underneath a curve and I kinda figured it out!  You saved my life man :')

Comment: Alright cool u go kill those tests girl.

Comment: Haha I'll try :) God bless!!